# Trigger specific python function in API based on GET request

Tags: python, django, rest

Right now, I have two servers; `webpage` and `compute`.

The `webpage` consists of a Django application and `compute` should do all the heavy lifting such that we don't waste resources on `webpage` and reduces the performance.

I'm thinking about making `compute` an API, where `webpage` sends requests to, and retrieves from.

An example would be:

```py
#webpage
import requests

data = requests.get("https://my_api.com/my_func")

# do something with data
```

```py
#compute

def my_func():
   data = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM database")
   return data

def get_func_to_call(request):
   if request.data=="my_func"
        return my_func
   else:
      return 404
```

I'm fairly new to APIs, thus I'm searching for suggestions, tutorials, books on how to create an API that would accomplish it.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Django already - you may be interested in [Django REST framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/) and find the module very beneficial to your project for creating API's.

I would also recommend as you are new to API's and showing interest in learning about them that you pick up a few HTTP tutorials to expand your understanding of headers, status codes etc and how to handle these within your language. I personally found this resource useful [MDN Web Docs on HHTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP).

Hopefully this can be of some use to you and answers any questions you may have had.